# Possible to create file from binary/base64 string

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to  create file from recieved base64 mdata?
Can sencha touch 2 or phonegap do this?

Background is: I  get base64 string of a file and need to store this data on users smartphone.

I know there are plugins for phonegap to do  this but  I would  do this
With  phonegap or sencha.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge no. But you can use the following:

[webtoolkit.base64.js](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html#.Uz7pDvldV8E)

To use just do the following:

    `//Decodeing
    Base64.decode(stringToDecode);
    //Encoding
    Base64.encode(stringToDecode);`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hmm thanks but thats  not  what i am looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

How big are the encoded strings. One thing you can do is to store them in the localstorage. But there are limitations on much can you store in the localstorage. Sencha touch provides api to store in the localstorage via stores.

Or you can use a phoengap sqlite plugin and store them on the device.